# scala: why code returns List[Any] and not List[String]?

Tags: scala

I am trying to learn the scala, and one thing confuses me is this:

Why following code returns `List[Any]` and not `List[String]`

```
def listToLowerCase(l: List[String]) = l.map(s=>if(s != null) s.toLowerCase)
```

is it because when string is `null` I am not even call `lowerCase` function? but shouldn't it return nothing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **Scala**, most control structures are *expressions* and not *statements*.
Thus, the `if-else` has to return a value. Since you do not have an `else` branch, the compiler inserts this `else ()`. So your code returns sometimes **Strings** other times **Unit** and the *LUB* of those two types is **Any**.

There are a couple of ways to solve this, one is to ensure the list doesn't have `nulls` before the `map` *(in general in **Scala** we never expect a `null`)*. Other is to return some default value when the string is `null` for example and empty string. Another one is to use the **Option** data type to represent missing values.

Here are some suggestions:

```
list.filter(_ != null).map(_.toLowerCase)
list.collect { case str if (str != null) => str.toLowerCase }
list.map(str => if (str != null) str.toLowerCase else "")
list.map(str => Option(str).map(_.toLowerCase))
list.map(str => Option(str).map(_.toLowerCase)).getOrElse("")
list.map(str => Option(str).fold(ifEmpty = "")(_.toLowerCase))
list.flatMap(str => Option(str).map(_.toLowerCase))
```

I would recommend you the last four, as direct manipulation of `null` in **Scala** is not recommended. Except if performance is a must and the allocation of `Option` is too expensive for your use case *(that is rarely the case)*.

Comment: There are productions called BlockStat, TemplateStat, TopStat, stat for "statement". https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/13-syntax-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

When `else` part of conditional expression is not provided

```
if(s != null) s.toLowerCase
```

then by default it expands to

```
if(s != null) s.toLowerCase else ()
```

where `s.toLowerCase` types to `String` whilst `()` types to `Unit`, hence the least upper bound of the two is `Any`. As per [SLS](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#conditional-expressions)

> A short form of the conditional expression eliminates the else-part.
>   The conditional expression `if (1) 2` is evaluated as if it was `if (1) 2 else ()`.

Note we could filter out `null` before lower-casing like so

```
List[String]("AA", null).flatMap(Option(_)).map(_.toLowerCase)
// res0: List[String] = List(aa)
```

because `Option(null)` is `None`.